# Using str.startswith to access a dataframe slice

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, startswith

I have a dataframe that with temperature values over the years, What I want to do is put all the rows that are from year 2015 into a new dataframe. Currently, the Date column is an object type with the str format looking like this: YYYY-MM-DD

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\whatever\weather.csv")

weather_2015 = df.loc[df.Date == df.Date.str.startswith("2015"), :]
weather_2015.head()
```

[this is what the data looks like in the main data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBtWK.png)

NOTE: if I do something like

```
weather_2015 = df.loc[df.Date == "2015-02-03", :]
weather_2015.head()
```

I get what I'd expect, dates only that match 2015-02-03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.Series.str.startswith` returns a boolean mask, you don't need to compare it to `df.Date` again. You could just index with it directly:

```
weather_2015 = df[df.Date.str.startswith("2015")]
```

You don't even need `.loc` here.

Note that if you want to make changes on this slice, you might prefer a copy, in which case you should call `df.copy`:

```
weather_2015 = df[df.Date.str.startswith("2015")].copy()
```

Comment: Dang, that was a quick response. Thank you very much!